# EC2 Java StartInstancesRequest goes from "pending" to "stopping" to "stopped"

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I have the following situation:

- Dedicated tenancy `m4.large` EC2 instance running RHEL6
- Manually starting it using the AWS Console works fine
- Lambda function (written in Java) that tries to start it, fails, because the instance state goes: stopped -> pending -> stopping -> stopped

I have a Lambda function that logs all EC2 state changes across the VPC as follows:

```js
'use strict';
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log('LogEC2InstanceStateChange');
  console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
  callback(null, 'Finished');
}
```

And another Lambda function that tries to start EC2 instances based on a schedule, written in Java, which is a lot of code, but the core of it is something like this:

```java
public void handleRequest(Object input, Context context) {
  final List<String> instancesToStart = getInstancesToStart(); //implementation not shown
  try {
    StartInstancesRequest startRequest = new StartInstancesRequest().withInstanceIds((String[]) instancesToStart.toArray());
    context.logger.log("StartInstancesRequest: " + startRequest.toString());
    StartInstancesResult res = ec2.startInstances(startRequest);
    context.logger.log("StartInstancesResult: " + res.toString());
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
    logException(e); //calls context.logger.log on the stack trace string
  }
}
```

The `instancesToStart` array is populated with instance IDs like `i-0abcdef1234567890`.

I create the Lambda functions and all required IAM roles, etc. using CloudFormation. Here is the bit describing the role/permissions for the Java-based Lambda function that does the work:

```yaml
Resources:
  EC2SchedulerRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
  EC2SchedulerPolicy:
    DependsOn:
      - EC2SchedulerRole
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Policy'
    Properties:
      PolicyName: ec2-scheduler-role
      Roles:
        - !Ref EC2SchedulerRole
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 'logs:*'
            Resource:
              - 'arn:aws:logs:*:*:*'
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 'ec2:DescribeInstanceAttribute'
              - 'ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus'
              - 'ec2:DescribeInstances'
              - 'ec2:StartInstances'
              - 'ec2:StopInstances'
              - 'ec2:DeleteTags'
            Resource:
              - '*'
```

What ends up happening is, according to the CloudWatch logs from the first function (the script that logs instance state transitions), we get:

```
Received event:
{
    "version": "0",
    "id": "<guid>",
    "detail-type": "EC2 Instance State-change Notification",
    "source": "aws.ec2",
    "account": "12345678",
    "time": "2019-06-20T19:01:35Z",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "resources": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:12345678:instance/i-0abcdef12345678"
    ],
    "detail": {
        "instance-id": "i-0abcdef12345678",
        "state": "pending"
    }
}

Received event:
{
    "version": "0",
    "id": "<guid>",
    "detail-type": "EC2 Instance State-change Notification",
    "source": "aws.ec2",
    "account": "12345678",
    "time": "2019-06-20T19:01:37Z",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "resources": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:12345678:instance/i-0abcdef12345678"
    ],
    "detail": {
        "instance-id": "i-0abcdef12345678",
        "state": "stopping"
    }
}

Received event:
{
    "version": "0",
    "id": "<guid>",
    "detail-type": "EC2 Instance State-change Notification",
    "source": "aws.ec2",
    "account": "12345678",
    "time": "2019-06-20T19:01:37Z",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "resources": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:12345678:instance/i-0abcdef12345678"
    ],
    "detail": {
        "instance-id": "i-0abcdef12345678",
        "state": "stopped"
    }
}
```

And according to the CloudWatch logs from the "worker" function (the function that actually tries to start the instances), we get:

```
StartInstancesRequest: {InstanceIds: [i-0abcdef12345678],}
StartInstancesResult: {StartingInstances: [{CurrentState: {Code: 0,Name: pending},InstanceId: i-0abcdef12345678,PreviousState: {Code: 80,Name: stopped}}]}
```

So it seems from the perspective of the Java-based Lambda that does the work, it's doing all it needs to do, to give the command to make the EC2 instance start; but then when the EC2 instance tries to actually start, it goes from "pending" to "stopping" to "stopped". If it didn't have permission, it wouldn't even get that far, right?

If it were an issue with the instance itself (e.g. hardware), I would expect that manually starting it using the AWS Console would **fail**. But it doesn't fail. It succeeds when started manually!

So what's happening? How do I diagnose this further? Is it permissions or is the instance screwed up?

I'm 99% sure this *isn't* due to a lack of available capacity in the AZ, because whenever I try to start the instance manually it always works. It's not an ephemeral issue or something that has only been happening recently. This has been persisting for several months like this, where manual starting works 100% of the time, and script based starting works 0% of the time.

Comment: It sounds like some of your code is sending an API call to stop the instance. Take a look at your **AWS CloudTrail** logs to see the actual API calls that are impacting your account and trace it back to the code.

Comment: Do you have secondary EBS volume attached to your ec2 ?

Comment: @SayantanMandal Yes I do. Three EBS volumes in total, one for root and one for /home and one for /data

Comment: @JohnRotenstein My CloudTrail logs do not show any `StopInstances` requests that coincide with the instances being started. There is literally nothing telling them to stop - they just stop. Instantly - or within seconds of being marked as "pending", anyway.

Comment: Can you see the log for the `StartInstances` command? No other calls soon after that command? Could it be that you have hit the maximum number of instances for your region, or for that instance type? (Check the Limits section in your EC2 management console.)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I do see the CloudTrail log for the `StartInstances` API call and it correctly shows the right instance ID. It isn't a limits issue, because as mentioned, I can manually start the instance just fine. In fact, my Lambda function tries to start the instance once *per hour* and reliably fails 100% of the time, but I can start the instance at literally any hour of any day manually from the AWS Console and it will spin up, no problem. That rules out limits entirely I believe.

Comment: @allquixotic starting ELB might be the issue. If you detach them and try start/stop using lambda, then it will work. Even if you block storage are KMS encrypted it will fail. If you like to start/stop EC2 along with ELB then try to add KMS and ELB related policies in your lambda IAM role.

Comment: For "ELB", you mean "EBS", right?

Comment: @SayantanMandal I found the issue was exactly what you thought it was: I had an encrypted EBS volume that needed KMS permissions to start the instance. I granted it `kms:*` and `ec2:*` and it works, so now I just need to whittle down the privileges to the minimum. But thank you! You can post an answer.

Comment: @allquixotic sorry, bad typo. Yes I mean EBS not ELB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Booting up EBS might be the issue. As you have mentioned EC2 is having 3 EBS volumes with KMS encryption. You have to provide KMS permission(kms:CreateGrant) to start your instances

```
{
        "Sid": "GrantAccess",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "kms:CreateGrant",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:::key/1234"
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I'd forgotten I'd encrypted the EBS volume on an instance with a particular KMS key, and had scheduled that key for deletion. Your answer prompted me to remember that!

Answer (score 0):

Try this policy and see if it works. If it does, there is the problem with the policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:Start*",
        "ec2:Stop*"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I found the issue was exactly what Sayantan Mandal thought it was: I had an encrypted EBS volume that needed KMS permissions to start the instance.